# Google Geocoding Api - только 1 запрос в день?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-geocoding-api

Раньше гугл давал 2500 бесплатных запросов в день для Geocoding API, теперь только 1. Что случилось и как это решить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решено путем введения платёжных даных левой карты и включения бесплатного пробного периода на год